# Show or Hide Specific KML Building

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I would like to use javascript to show or hide a  specific kml building, given that I know everything about it.
Is there a way?

Comment: Do you have any code to show that you have attempted this on you own?

Answer (score 0):

" given that I know everything about it" let me think that you also have the id of that particular building.
If so, you can simply use this code sample to hide it:

```
var myKmlPlacemark = ge.getElementById("myId");
myKmlPlacemark.setVisibility(false);
```

If you do not have the element's id, i suggest you to change your logic so that you have it. Everything will be MUCH EASIER!
Bye